# How does hadoop 1.0 implements High available

Tags: hadoop

Since Hadoop 2.0 there is a backup node to implement high availability, but now I'm using Hadoop 1.0, so I don't have any idea how to solve the single node failure of name node. Could you please give me some advice.

One question: In Hadoop 2.0, if the name node failed, will the backup node become the name node automatically or does it need to be changed manually?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is an old question... not sure if it still applies...

Hadoop 1.0 does not have High Availability.  Before 2.0, Hadoop had a Secondary Namenode, which would help recover a Namenode, but not automatically and not High Availability.

So, the easy answer to: "How does hadoop 1.0 implement High Availability?" is: "It doesn't"